# „von zwei Pfund grünen Erbsen“ (apposition) or „von zwei Pfund grüner Erbsen“ (genitive)?

Tags: grammatical-case

According to my grammar texts (*Hammer’s Grammar* by Martin Durrell or *Modern German Grammar* by Dodd, Klapper, etc.), the noun phrase that denote what is measured should stand in apposition to the measurement notions, hence *von zwei Pfund grünen Erbsen*, where both *Pfund* and *Erbsen* are in the dative case.

On the other hand, according to Duden’s *Richtiges und Gutes Deutsch*, *Erbsen* should be in the genitive case if *Pfund* is in the dative case, hence *von zwei Pfund grüner Erbsen*, where *grüner* is in accordance to the plural genitive case.

Besides, I am wondering why *Pfund* needn’t be in the plural form in measurement constructions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A measure of two pound of green peas would be (nominative, with preposition)

> … zwei Pfund von grünen Erbsen …

The alternative form in replacing the preposition with a  genitive of measure would be

> … zwei Pfund grüner Erbsen …

and the colloquial, everyday form which is most commonly used today would be (all nominative, no preposition)

> … zwei Pfund grüne Erbsen …

All can be used interchangeably, the first two are aging.

When the *Erbsen* is in dative case like in

> ich koche ein Gericht aus zwei Pfund von grünen Erbsen

is possible as well as

> Ich koche ein Gericht aus zwei Pfund grüner Erbsen

both of the above are grammatically correct, but pretty uncommon in day-to-day speech and most commonly replaced with

> Ich koche ein Gericht aus zwei Pfund grünen Erbsen.

With regards to the expected plural on *Pfund*: German doesn’t pluralize common units of measure.

> Das Brett ist zwei Fuss breit.

Uncommon units of measure (*Glas*, *Tasse*) *can* be flexed.

> Ich trank drei Gläser Wasser vs. Ich trank drei Glas Wasser

And feminine “uncommon” units of measure ending in *-e* are always flexed

> Ich trank drei Tassen Kaffee — here singular doesn’t work

Comment: I think *von* was only used as an example of a preposition demanding the dative case.

Comment: Allright, re-worked the answer

Comment: A second category of units that is always flexed is time units: *zwei Tage Bedenkzeit*, *drei Wochen Urlaub*.

Comment: @Uwe Yes, there are more exceptions. Constructs like "Ab einer Höhe von zwei *Metern* wird mir schwindlig" require pluralized units as well.