# measured noun in nominative case

Tags: grammatical-case

[Here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/29658/von-zwei-pfund-gr%c3%bcnen-erbsen-apposition-or-von-zwei-pfund-gr%c3%bcner-erbsen-g) in this link option has been given for a measured noun that it could be in a nominative case. Then I would like to know is it possible to put the genitive noun *Kindes* in nominative case? Because it is already an attributive of the noun *Vater.*

> 1. Er ist der Vater eines zwei Kilogramm schweren Kindes. (with genitive)
> 2. Er ist der Vater eines zwei Kilogramm schweres Kind. (with nominitive)

Answer (score 5):

Here you don't say

> zwei Kilogramm Kind (two kilograms of child)

like

> zwei Kilogramm Rindfleisch (two kilograms of beef)

In the examples above *zwei Kilogram* is a measurement of the noun. But in your example it is part of an attribute of the noun. (The whole attribute is *zwei Kilogramm schwer*)

Compare:

> ein **kleines** Kind (a **small** child)
>   ein **puppenspielendes** Kind (a **puppet playing** child)
>   ein **mit Puppen spielendes** Kind (a child **playing with dolls**)
>   ein **zwei Kilogramm schweres** Kind (a **two-kilogram** child)
>   ein **zwei Kilogramm wiegendes** Kind (a child **weighing two kilograms**)

Since it is an attribute, the noun must have the same case as if the attribute wasn't there:

> Er ist der Vater eines **Kindes.**
>   Er ist der Vater eines *zwei Kilogramm schweren* **Kindes.**

The adjective *schwer* in *zwei Kilogramm schwer* must be declined the same way as if the measurement *zwei Kilogramm* wasn't there:

> Er ist der Vater eines **schweren** Kindes.
>   Er ist der Vater eines *zwei Kilogramm* **schweren** Kindes.

Note, that here the measurement *zwei Kilogramm* does not refer to the noun (*Kind*). It refers to the adjective *schwer* which, together with the measurement, forms an attribute of the noun.